# Numbers given in error messages in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I don't understand well the numbers given by error messages in general with Node.js

```
   at /home/gbusey/file.js:525:2
   at Frobnicator.refrobulate (/home/gbusey/business-logic.js:424:21)
   at Actor.<anonymous> (/home/gbusey/actors.js:400:8)
   at increaseSynergy (/home/gbusey/actors.js:701:6)
```

In the previous message for example, what does 525:2 mean ?

(I dont write code because my question is not about a particular code but about the number in the error messages in general)

Comment: nodejs 16: On my case point to the line 3 but there is nothing in that line ` at SimplePipelineExecutor.start (src/main/node/pipelines/SimplePipelineExecutor.js:3:615)` I think latest version is minifying the code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called a *stacktrace*.

The function calls through which the error is propagated is shown. The numbers you are asking about represent `<line number>:<column number>` in the file.
Check the [error stack section](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_propagation_and_interception) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

> what does 525:2 mean

Line 525, offset 2 (of the file `/home/gbusey/file.js`)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are line:position, so 252:2 would be that the program stopped on line 252 at the second character.